# Constructing a table from a MySQL database, and then being able to filter the table without reloading the page

Tags: php, html, mysql, filtering

I'm working on a website that presents leaderboard data from a MySQL database as a table, that which can be filtered and searched through by the user. I was able to construct the table through PHP calls, such as

> php echo $row['ranking'];

Similarly, I was able to create a pagination that limits the MySQL query to 50 rows per page.

What I haven't been able to achieve, is the filtering/searching of the data, as well as a pagination that doesn't require the reloading of the page. I attempted to create filtering through PHP variables

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM New_2v2_Data $filters";
```

but couldn't get it to work outside of just editing the PHP code.

```
                $racevar = '%';
                $classvar = '%';
                $specvar = '%';
                $playervar = '%';
                $realmvar = '%';
                $factionvar = '%';
                $r1 = '0';
                $r2 = '1800';

                $race ="raceId LIKE '$racevar'";
                $class = "classId LIKE '$classvar'";
                $spec ="specId LIKE '$specvar'";
                $player ="player LIKE '$playervar'";    
                $realm ="realmName LIKE '$realmvar'";
                $faction="factionId LIKE '$factionvar'";
                $rating ="rating between $r1 and $r2";

$filters = "WHERE $race AND $class AND $spec AND $player AND $realm AND $faction AND $rating";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM New_2v2_Data $filters"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql); //run the query
```

I've found filtering solutions for individual variables, for example names, but I haven't been able to find anything that takes in multiple variables into account. Even then, the filtering only worked on tables that were static.

I was thinking maybe if a dropdown/checkbox were to change a PHP variable depending on what is chosen, and then reloading the PHP for the table to include the additional "WHERE" statement, filtering could work.

Some advice on how I would go about doing this would be great, thank you.

Comment: Do not use the mysql functions. They are depreciated and gone completely in PHP 7. Use the mysqli or PDO functions instead and use prepared statements. Otherwise, your code is suseptable to SQL Injection.

Comment: To refresh the table without reloading the page, you'll need to use AJAX to retrieve the data, and Javascript to re-build the table with the data received.

Comment: @SloanThrasher It's not 'mysql functions'; it's PHP's mysql_ API. And it's *deprecated*. This may or may not have impacted its monetary value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally include the various limits and build the SQL just from those which have something set.

```
$racevar = 'a';     // A value to show when this would be included
$classvar = '%';
$specvar = '%';
$playervar = '%';
$realmvar = '%';
$factionvar = '%';
$r1 = '0';
$r2 = '1800';

$condition= [];
$bindData = [];
if ( $racevar != '%'){
    $condition[] ="raceId LIKE ?";
    $bindData[] = $racevar;
}
if ( $classvar != '%'){
    $condition[] = "classId LIKE ?";
    $bindData[] = $classvar;
}
// Repeat above for all of the conditions
if ( $r1 != 0 or $r2 != 0 ) {
    $condition[] = "rating between ? and ?";
    $bindData[] = $r1;
    $bindData[] = $r2;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM New_2v2_Data";
if ( count($condition) > 0 ) {
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(' and ', $condition);
}
echo $sql;
```

The idea is to build a list of conditions, only when the values have something which is a limit.  This can then be added as a where clause.

You then can have various input fields/select fields which allow the user to select the criteria and call this routine with the selections.

I've updated the answer to use bind variables, so that using prepare will give you more security and then you can either bind the values or (using PDO) execute with the array of bind values.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I just had a quick question concerning the BETWEEN value I was using before ($r1 and $r2). I understand that I would  I would change the $condition[] to = rating between $r1 and $r2, but how would this work for the if statement?

Comment: If $r1 and $r2 are numbers, then add something like the bit I've added in the answer.  All you probably need is that if either of them is set, then add it in.  If you set one though you will need both set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the filters selectable or dynamic in a way that you can pass them on to your SQL statement.

Your solution for the dropdown could be one of them indeed. You could even do that with a 'search' input text field. Then you make your WHERE statement:

```
WHERE (`column1` LIKE '%$search%' OR `column2` LIKE '%$search%' OR `column3` LIKE '%$search%',) LIMIT 0,10
```